# Two ng-inits not working

Tags: angularjs

I have two ng-inits located here.

```
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3 style="font-size: 26px">
                <editable ng-init="option={title:'Event Title Here'};" model="option.title">{{option.title}}</editable>
            <!-- <editable model="option.title">{{option.title}}</editable> -->
        </h3>
            <h5>
                <editable ng-init="option={description:'Event description Here'};" model="option.description">{{option.description}}</editable>
            </h5>
        </div>
```

What happens is that the first ng-init is ignored and the second one is used. I need both to be used

I have no idea why, I am wanting to have both `{{}}` areas to have a placeholder, and this is the only way i have found out how to so far.

Comment: They override each other, merge them into one.

Comment: don't use ng-init , this is not it's intended purpose. Beyond that you are changing the same scope variable. If you want isolated instances need to use isolated scope in directive. Need to update question with expected behavior wanted

Comment: Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit if you don't know how ng-init works

Answer (score 1):

You are actually overwriting the object created in the first ng-init with the one created in the second ng-init. You should either have an upper ng-init initalize the option object at `{}` and let your current two ng-inits set their particular field, or initialize the whole object in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided anything about an `editable` directive, I'm assuming they don't have child scopes. Thus `option` is being set for a parent scope both elements share, ng-init does not create a child scope.

A couple things

1. [Dont use ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)
2. Why not just declare `option = {title:'Event Title Here', description:'Event description Here'}`? If it's the same entity, it should be the same object, and just reference different properties in the DOM. Thats what MV* is about.
3. As per 1, it's best to declare your data in a controller, rather than on the DOM.